# Get keyword value C++

Tags: c++, parsing, keyword

I am using C++ to read a file and make some calculations. I need to save the value of a keyword but I am having problems. I managed to read the file line by line and find the keyword in the string. But I get different results if I check it with cout of if I assign it to a variable and print it with cout.

The file has the following format
vtk DataFile Version 2.0

```
#Generated by lpp.py
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 3 float
```

And the code that I am using is:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int nPart = 0;
    string fileName = "liggghts_simPart";
    string extension = ".vtk";
    string keyword = "POINTS";
    string currentFile;
    string line;
    int numLines = 0;   // counter for line reading
    currentFile = "liggghts_simPart0500.vtk";

    //Open the curren file
    ifstream fileToOpen;
    fileToOpen.open(currentFile);

    for (int i = 0; numLines <= 4 &&  getline(fileToOpen, line); ++numLines){

    }

    cout << line << endl;
    size_t found = line.find(keyword);
    nPart = line[ found + keyword.size() + 1 ];     // get key value
    cout << line[ found + keyword.size() + 1 ] << endl;
    cout << nPart << endl;
}
```

The output that I get is

```
POINTS 3 float
3
51
```

So why I'm getting different outputs? I should get the value of the keyword in both cases which is 3.

It would be great if someone can give me a hand!

Thanks,
Mauro

Comment: You do not check if `line.find` is successful.  Your code just assumes it found the string and goes on its merry way.

Comment: `nPart = line[found+keyword.size()+1];` reads a character value and stores it in `nPart`. At the very least, the code should convert that character value to an integer value, by subtracting `'0'`. But that only works for a single digit. The code really needs to do a proper conversion, probably with `std::stoi`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; numLines <= 4` you read 5 lines before you do anything with `line`, but I count only 4 lines in the file

Comment: When I compiled the program, I've got 
 
32, and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are casting to `int` without properly converting the value. In [ASCII](https://ascii.cl/), the numeric value for the symbol `"3"` is `51`, which is the output you're getting.

You should convert to integer using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

```
nPart = std::stoi(line.substr(found + keyword.size() + 1, 1));
```

However, as mentioned in comments, the method you are using to locate the value will only work for single digits. If you are likely ever to encounter values greater than `9`, you should find a better way to tokenise the string (e.g. by splitting on `" "`).